# MySQL 5.6 installation issue in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I had MySQL 5.5 and I tried variety of ways to upgrade to MySQL 5.6 but it didn't work properly.

When I do:

```
test@test:~$ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
[sudo] password for test: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client-5.6 : Breaks: mysql-server-core-5.6 (< 5.6.22-1~) but 5.6.16-1~exp1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

When I try to:

```
test@test:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server-core-5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.6 mysql-client-core-5.6
  mysql-common mysql-common-5.6
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-server-core-5.6
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 378 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,940 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,822 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 229415 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.6_5.6.35-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.6 (5.6.35-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+0.1) over (5.6.16-1~exp1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-core-5.6_5.6.35-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+0.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/innochecksum', which is also in package mysql-client-5.6 5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-core-5.6_5.6.35-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+0.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The dpkg error says 
mysql-server-core-5.6_5.6.35-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+0.1_amd64.deb is trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/innochecksum' which is already installed by mysql-client-5.6 5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 package.

You need to remove mysql-client-5.6 and other depending packages first by using:

`sudo apt-get autoremove` and then install mysql-server or phpmysqladmin.